# QueryDisplayConfig - proper documentation missing

Tags: c++, api, wdk

I am trying to use the `QueryDisplayConfig()` and `SetDisplayConfig()` functions from the WDK.

As per the documentation, it takes the following parameters:

```
LONG WINAPI SetDisplayConfig(
  __in UINT32 numPathArrayElements,
  __in_opt DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO* pathArray,
  __in UINT32 numModeInfoArrayElements,
  __in_opt DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO* modeInfoArray,
  __in UINT32 Flags
);
```

The `DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO` and `DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO` structures are not documented properly or I am unable to understand their meaning.

Can anyone please explain or point me to information related to `DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO` and `DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO`? The MSDN website and documentation are not explaining these things conceptually. These things are normally handled well by Display Settings applet but I want to achieve similar results using this API.

I want to understand what information these structures contain, how to interpret it, and how to change various values so that I can get the desired results like cloning, extending, attaching and unattaching displays.

I want to understand concepts like Path array, Mode info array, etc.

Comment: as microsofts documentation is still not present, did you figure it out or find any source that explains these structs?

Answer (score -1):

Links to MSDN for all functions and explanations:

[QueryDisplayConfig()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/hardware/ff569215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[SetDisplayConfig()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/hardware/ff553945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

[DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/hardware/ff553933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)